# The zeros of an analytic function are isolated

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading a homework problem. I have to prove that the zeros of analytic functions are isolated, what does "isolated zeros" mean? Could you, please, examples or some drawings? In my understanding isolated zeros mean the zeros of the function have no multiplicity.

Comment: Isolated $0$s mean that for each $z$ such that $f(z)=0$ then there exists an open set $U$ containing $z$ with the property that $f(w) \neq 0$ for every $w \neq z$ in $U$

Answer (score 10):

$f$ has an isolated zero at $z_0$ if $f(z_0)=0$ and for some $r>0, 0<|z-z_0|<r\implies f(z)\ne 0 $.  This has nothing to do with multiplicity:  $z^2$ has an isolated zero at $z=0$

Answer (score 3):

One definition of the zeroes of a function $f$ being isolated is that whenever $f(z) = 0$ there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $f(w) \neq 0$ for every $w$ such that $0 < |z-w| < \varepsilon$.

A side remark is that you probably mean to talk about non-zero analytic functions.

Answer (score 1):

zeroes are said to be isolated if for each zero $x_i$, you can find a neighborhood $U_i$ of $x_i$ so that $U_i$ does not contain any of the other zeroes.

In other words, you can draw a little disk around each zero so that it contains *only* that zero.

To see that this is really important, consider the function $\sin(1/x)$ with $x>0$, which is continuous but has many concentrated zeroes.

Comment: The zeroes of $\sin(1/x)$ are isolated. A better example would be $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$.